# Vertically add numpy array to itself

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to add an array of `(174, 2, 2)` to itself vertically. So far I am able to do it in non-numpy way:

```
import numpy as np
cm1 = np.random.rand(174, 2, 2)
temp_array = np.zeros([2, 2])

for _content in cm1:
    temp_array = np.add(temp_array, _content)

print(temp_array)
```

I am able to get the results, but is there a numpy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) with parameter `axis=0` as:

```
cm1.sum(axis=0)
array([[82.39817762, 84.41947252],
       [91.82740901, 83.53547764]])
```

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks for that.